# Calling PostGIS functions within Ruby

Tags: ruby, postgis, squeel, rgeo

I need to execute the PostGIS function `st_intersection` within an SQL SELECT clause in Ruby. At the moment I am doing it as raw SQL query:

```sql
sql_query = "SELECT id, ST_ASEWKT(ST_INTERSECTION(geometry, ?)) FROM trips WHERE status='active';"
intersections = Trip.execute_sql(sql_query, self[:geometry].to_s)
```

This way has the disadvantage that I receive the result as text and I need to parse the objects out of the strings. Much nicer would be the use of the ActiveRecord interface to make queries. However, I could not find any solution yet to run PostGIS functions (e.g. `st_intersection`) within ActiveRecord.

An earlier version of the activerecord-postgis-adapter's [README](https://github.com/rgeo/activerecord-postgis-adapter/pull/147/commits/ebddf39b67ad11c63fa2c8554729b322b66a7f6b#diff-04c6e90faac2675aa89e2176d2eec7d8) showed a nice example using the gem `squeel`:

```rb
my_polygon = get_my_polygon    # Obtain the polygon as an RGeo geometry
MySpatialTable.where{st_intersects(lonlat, my_polygon)}.first
```

As this is not part of the current README anymore, I am wondering whether this is not recommended or if there are any better alternatives.

Comment: `find_by_sql` perhaps.

Comment: @maxpleaner Using `find_by_sql` returns the Trip objects only, not the result produced by the function `st_intersection`.

Comment: Try `Trip.find_by_sql(["SELECT id, ST_ASEWKT(ST_INTERSECTION(geometry, ?)) AS st_asewk FROM trips WHERE status='active'"])[0].st_asewk` The result is there, it's easier to access if you give it an alias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems to solve here.

The first is using an SQL function within a `.select` clause. Ordinarily this is pretty easy—you just use `AS` to give the result a name. Here's an example from the [ActiveRecord Rails Guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.0/active_record_querying.html#group):

```
Order.select("date(created_at) as ordered_date, sum(price) as total_price").group("date(created_at)")
```

The resulting Order objects would have `ordered_date` and `total_price` attributes.

This brings us to the second problem, which is that Rails doesn't give us an easy way to parameterize a `select` (i.e. use a `?` placeholder), so (as far as I can tell) you'll need to do it yourself with [`sanitize_sql_array`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Sanitization/ClassMethods.html#method-i-sanitize_sql_array):

```
sql_for_select_intersection = sanitize_sql_array([
  "ST_ASEWKT(ST_INTERSECTION(geometry, ?)) AS intersection",
  geometry,
])
```

This will return a sanitized SQL fragment like `ST_ASEWKT(ST_INTERSECTION(geometry, '...'))`, which you can then use to specify a field in `select`:

```
Trip.where(status: "active").select(:id, sql_for_select_intersection))
```

The resulting query will return Trip objects with `id` and `intersection` attributes.